# Problem with introspection of GraphQL ASP.NET Core Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphiql, graphql.net

I can't see the schema of my GraphQL Graph. The introspection is not working when I use Web API GraphQL Controller as endpoint.

I've currently tried with GraphiQl and the UI.Playground library

```
[Route("graphql")]
[ApiController]
public class GraphQLController : ControllerBase
```

I expect to see the schema and the types using introspection provided by the GraphQL.NET library, but unfortunately I don't. I'm currently using Insomnia Client which fetches the schema, but GraphiQL and GraphQL.Server.Ui.Playground can't do the job.
I'm using GraphQL.NET 2.4.0 by Joe McBride

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody]GraphQLQuery query)
```

Where

```
public class GraphQLQuery
{
    public string OperationName { get; set; }
    public string NamedQuery { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject Variables { get; set; }
}
```

And image of never ending loading
[image]

Comment: please share your Post method on the controller and also a screenshot of the problem you are having with the GraphiQL/Playground UI. TIA

Comment: I'll provide extensive information later

Comment: The problem is that the schema is never loaded, and the autocomplete of the query types is not suggesting anything. The controller itself works when i send request.

Comment: See if your dev console is throwing any error or not. I never faced this problem. You can check this repo and see if you are missing something - https://github.com/fiyazbinhasan/GraphQLCore

Answer (score 0):

May be late to the party, but here is a possible solution for .NET Core 3.0 Web API.

**Fix CORS and add default GQL endpoint in Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services
    .AddGraphQL(o => o.ExposeExceptions = true)
    .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  app.UseCors(o => o.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());  // CORS settings
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseEndpoints(o => o.MapControllers());

  app.UseGraphQLPlayground(new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions 
  { 
    GraphQLEndPoint = "/services/queries/groups"  // default GraphQL endpoint  
  });
}
```

**If GQL playground still doesn't hit your controller, try dynamic parameter**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("services/queries/groups")]
public async Task<dynamic> Items([FromBody] dynamic queryParams)
{
  var schema = new Schema
  {
    Query = new GroupsQuery() // create query and populate it from dynamic queryParams
  };

  var response = await schema.ExecuteAsync(o =>
  {
    //o.Inputs = queryParams.variables;
    o.Query = queryParams.query;
    o.OperationName = queryParams.operationName;
    o.UserContext = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    o.ValidationRules = DocumentValidator.CoreRules;
    o.ExposeExceptions = true;
    o.EnableMetrics = true;
  });

  return response;
}
```